# $\forall n>0 \text{ }\exists x\text{ } \forall i \text{ }(1\le i\le n) \implies (x+i \text{ is composite})$

Tags: logic, induction, computer-science

$$\forall n>0 \text{ }\exists x\text{ } \forall i \text{ }(1\le i\le n) \implies (x+i \text{ is composite})$$

This was in a mathematical induction lecture in Mathematics for Computer Science. A composite number is one that 'can be made by multiplying **other** numbers', i.e. not prime.

I've figured out that it probably means that $x+n$ is composite while $x+n+1$ is not (or is a prime)? But I'm not sure what I should be doing to prove this exactly. I hope that's enough information.

EDIT: I have the answer, but it's still above my understanding.

1: Given $n>0, \text{ let }x=(n+1)!+1$.

2: Let $i\geq1 \text{ and } i\leq n, \text{ and consider }x+1$.

3: $\text{Note }x+i=(n+1)!+(i+1).$

4: Note $(i+1) | (n+1)!\text{, since } 2\leq i+1\leq n+1.$

5:Also $(i+1)|(i+1).\text{ So, }(i+1)|(x+i).$

6: $\therefore x+i$ is composite.

7: $\forall n \text{ } \exists x \text{ }\forall (1\leq i\leq n): x+i \text{ is composite}$

In line 1: I suppose $x=(n+1)!+1$ is essentially all possible values of x? I understand that the factorial probably contributes to the overall expression being always composite (since it's a multiple of more than just 1 and x+i). I don't fully understand the need for the two $+1$s though.

I'm assuming the $|$ symbol means 'set of'. Is this correct? But from line 3 and beyond I'm already unsure of the meaning of the working.

Comment: I think you mean $1\le i \le n$. You just need to find some $x$ such that $x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n$ are all composite. This says nothing about $x+n+1$.

Comment: This formula gives $at\;least\;n$ consecutive integers, not exactly $n$. Actually I think it is not possible to find exactly $n$ consecutive composite numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the proof, I'll try to explain the reasoning behind each line:

1: Given $n>0, \text{ let }x=(n+1)!+1.$

- This is the value of $x$ that we choose, that we want to show obey the given property: $\forall (1\leq i\leq n): x+i \text{ is composite}$

2: Let $i\geq1 \text{ and } i\leq n, \text{ and consider }x+1.$

- Here, specifying the bounds of $i$

3: $\text{Note }x+i=(n+1)!+(i+1).$

- Here we expand the value of $x+i$ for use in later steps

4: Note $(i+1) | (n+1)!\text{, since } 2\leq i+1\leq n+1.$

- The expression $a|b$ denotes "$a$ divides $b$" (or $a$ is a factor of $b$), which $i+1$ is clearly a factor of $(n+1)!$

5:Also $(i+1)|(i+1).\text{ So, }(i+1)|(x+i).$

- We show $(i+1)$ divides itself, so when adding to $(n+1)!$ from above, the $(i+1)$ also divides the sum

6: $\therefore x+i$ is composite.

- Since $(i+1)$ is a factor greater than 1, we can conclude $x+1$ is composite. (This step is why the +1 is crucial, we don't want $i=1$ to be the factor of $x$)

7: $\forall n \text{ } \exists x \text{ }\forall (1\leq i\leq n): x+i \text{ is composite}$

- Q.E.D.

Comment: This was a great explanation, I understand it completely. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since $i \le i \le n$ doesn't make much sense, I think the statement should be

$\forall n>0 \space \exists x \space \forall i \space (1\le i\le n) \implies (x+i \text{ is composite})$

which says that for all positive $n$ there is an $x$ such that the $n$ consecutive integers from $x+1$ to $x+n$ inclusive are composite. In other words, for every positive $n$, we can find a stretch of $n$ consecutive integers that contains no primes.

To prove this, imagine you knew an integer $y$ that was divisible by every integer from $2$ to $n+1$. What does this tell you about $y+2, y+3, y+4, \dots, y+n+1$ ?

Comment: Your correction is right, I made the edit, thanks! I also added more information just now. Still in process of editing the post...

Your last line gave me a lot of insight! I'll think about it after I finish

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of $$x=(n+1)!+1$$ ?

Comment: I assume this is the equation that lets x be composite for all n>0? I do not know why the +1s are there though. I have an idea why the factorial is there, since it essentially includes all the multiples from some range.