# A way to find exactly $n$ consecutive composite numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-gaps

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3865389/forall-n0-text-exists-x-text-forall-i-text-1-le-i-le-n-implies) quite simple question, I tried to play  with the formula.

$(n+1)!+(i+1);\;1\le i\le n$

Which gives *at least* $n$ consecutive composite numbers. But I've found that very often they are more than $n$.

For $n=3$ we have $3! +2=8; 3!+3=9;3!+4=10$ there are exactly $3$ composite consecutive numbers

But for $n=11$ I've found $15$ consecutive composite numbers.
For $n=27$ there are $45$.

I wonder if there is a way to find $n$ such that there are ***exactly*** $n$ composite consecutive numbers.

Comment: Please clarify how $n=11$ gives $15$ consecutive composites and the same for $n=27$

Comment: Do you mean with "exactly $n$" consecutive composite numbers that we get a prime in the next step ?

Comment: My suspicion is that this is unknown. It is one thing to find an occurrence of $p_{n+1} - p_n = 8.$ It is another to demenad the difference be 1000000.

Comment: @Peter I've edited my question. Hope it is more clear.

Comment: @Raffaele i think what you are asking would be more clearly stated that you want to find a string of n integers, $a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$ such that the number preceding $a_1$ and the number following $a_n$ are both prime. Interesting question if thats the case ill think about it. Find a formula for such a thing isnt going to be possible as we have tried for a long time to find a formula that is always prime n failed but proving existence might be doable.

Comment: @Faust I have tried with Mathematica up to 1000 and there is no sequence that satisfies this property. Proving that it doesn't exist for any $n$ is out of my league, tho.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $$2+(n+1)!\space,\space 3+(n+1)!\space,\space ... \space,\space (n+1)+(n+1)!$$

Then for the first term, you can factor a $2$, for the second a $3$, etc. Thus there are $(n+1)-2+1=n$ terms in the sequence which are all consecutive and composite numbers.

Comment: I'm sorry. My question was unclear. I edited and hope it is more clear now

Comment: If you delete your answer I can delete my question